# Z transform individually each slice of a list of 3D arrays in R

Tags: r, for-loop, multidimensional-array, apply

I have a list with 14 three-dimensional arrays (see extension below).

- Each array represents one climate model.
- They contain euclidean distance values (385x373) for 4 different climate parameters (= 4 slices).

My aim is to:

1. Find for each climate model the 10 grid points with the over all climate parameters best fit, i.e. smallest euclidean distance. Therefore, I want to z-transform all 14x4 slices (=climate parameter) individually.
2. After that, I want to average the z-transformed values over the 4 climate parameters, so that each climate model exists of a simple 2D arrays. I want to pick out of each of these matrices the 10 values/grid points with the best fit, i.e. the smallest euclidean distance.

The following code returns for *ztrans* a list of 14 matrices with each `ncol = 4` and `nrow = 143,605` (385x373) instead of my desired list of 14 matrices with each containing `ncol = 385` and `nrow = 373`. So I suggest something went wrong in the calculation:

```
ztrans <- list()
mean.ztrans <- list()
min.values <- list()

for (i in 1:length(models.list)) {

  ztrans[[i]] <- apply(models.list[[i]], MARGIN = 3, function(x) (x - mean(x))/sd(x))

  mean.ztrans[[i]] <- apply(ztrans[[i]], c(1,2), function(x) mean(x))

  min.values[[i]] <-  which(rank(mean.ztrans[[i]], ties.method='min') <= 10)

}
```

The two final functions worked in another `for` loop without problem. The problem seems to be rather in the *ztrans* object. I think I'm missing something regarding the indexing or the margin. But I tried everything, and I could not find any solution. Thank you a lot for any help!

EXTENSION: here is sample output of my *models.list* data

```
dput(lapply(models.list[3:4], "[", 1:2, 1:4, 1:3))

list(structure(c(2.09909189486221e-05, 2.11098699577055e-05, 
2.09089422854975e-05, 2.09959065239106e-05, 2.09165332916687e-05, 
2.09696558968188e-05, 2.09679193622951e-05, 2.09035656412878e-05, 
14.5389879862467, 14.4131762186686, 14.4208234998915, 14.3084695604112, 
14.2621593051487, 14.1757117377387, 14.0674346923828, 14.0071330600315, 
17.9918197631836, 17.7803471035428, 17.9010253058539, 17.6852742513021, 
17.7930487738715, 17.6089325798882, 17.6458153618707, 17.5119138929579
), .Dim = c(2L, 4L, 3L)), structure(c(2.6861608213655e-05, 2.694993779184e-05, 
2.68257257009728e-05, 2.69702473711078e-05, 2.70261560656361e-05, 
2.70366213853333e-05, 2.71945821715919e-05, 2.71174184201812e-05, 
12.9470822652181, 12.9592661539714, 12.8425070020888, 12.831266784668, 
12.6887640211317, 12.7041046990289, 12.5058373345269, 12.5362530178494, 
17.7252056545681, 17.5347224765354, 17.6345549689399, 17.4180641174316, 
17.5483113606771, 17.3722513834635, 17.4406307644314, 17.3106827629937
), .Dim = c(2L, 4L, 3L)))
```

Comment: Can you share a small sample input? Do you have any missing values in your data?

Comment: Also, just to simplify a little bit, you don't need to use an anonymous function to wrap `mean()`, you can just `apply(..., c(1, 2), mean)`. Similarly, for the `ztrans` definition you can `apply(..., MARGIN = 3, scale)`

Comment: An easy way to share a little bit of copy/pasteable data is `dput`. Pasting `dput(lapply(models.list[1:2], "[", 1:2, 1:4, 1:3))` should give us a little sample of the first two models.

Comment: I think the problem is that the result of your function for scaling the matrix returns an (n*k) * 4 matrix (four very long columns), as opposed to a list of matrices. You can bang this back into your desired shape by re-writing the function as `function(x) array(scale(x), c(385, 373, 4))`. From there should work.

Comment: @Gregor: The dput function as described gives me that Error: "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds." I never used dput before and I don't know why subscript should be out of bounds as my list has a length of 14. Some idea? Thanks!

Comment: @gfgm I think you are right with your suggestion. The function returns a list with length 14 (that is correct!), but instead of matrices with ncol = 385(n) and nrow = 373(k), it returns matrices with ncol = 4 and nrow = (n*k) as you say. So I suppose something went wrong in the calculation. I will try your solution later today. Thanks!

Comment: If each element of `models.list` is a 3-dimensional array with at least 2 rows, 4 columns, and 3 slices, my `dput` code should work. Maybe it would be better if you just did a `dput` of some small subset of the first one, `models.list[[1]]`. Something like `models.list[[1]][1:2, 1:3, ]`. Find a subset that works, then wrap it in `dput()` and paste the result into the question.

Comment: @Gregor I see where the problem is. Just the second file in the list only has two slices (as only two climate parameters have been simulated with that climate model). I didn't mention in my question...sorry! I pasted the result of dput for the third and fourth file of my list in my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Gregor: Good suggestion for simplifying my code, thanks!